# How to get selected value onChange of react redux-form react-select

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I'm using redux-forms fileds with a react-select. After changing the value the onChange function does show the value. I want to check the value and for specific values open a dialog box to let the user confirm the selection.

```
import SelectBox from "react-select"

const checkValue= (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}

const Select= ({...props }) => (
  <Field
    {...props}
    component={SelectBox}
    onChange={e => checkValue(e)}
    items={myItems}
    })}
  />
)
```

Comment: Please check my answer, doest it fit you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user **formValues**  - it is a redux-form selector which returns you all the data from the form.
https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/formvalues.md/

But you should know that once you apply formValues selector to a component it will react to every change in every field (not only the ones you need to look at). This can worsen the performance of this component.